# Перенос и расчет данных из одной таблицы Excel в другую Python

Tags: python

Дано: xlsx файл с таблицей
1 столбец - ФИО
2 столбец - наличие у ФИО атрибута A
3 столбец - наличие у ФИО атрибута B
Необходимо:
создать новый xlsx файл с таблицей результатов:

- подсчитать общее количество ячеек по столбцу 1 (без учета заголовка),
- подсчитать кол-во ФИО с атрибутом А и В,
- подсчитать кол-во ФИО с только атрибутом А
- подсчитать кол-во ФИО с только атрибутом В
- подсчитать кол-во ФИО без атрибутов

Нашел как перенести данные из одного столбца таблицы в другую с помощью openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
book = openpyxl.Workbook()
book.remove(book.active)
sheet = book.create_sheet('Result1')
book.save('Задание1.xlsx')
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('ФИО.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1['Contracts']
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Задание1.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Result1']

target_cell_num = 1

for i,cell in enumerate(ws1['A']):
    ws2[f'A{target_cell_num + i}'] = cell.value

wb2.save(filename='Задание1.xlsx')
```

А как посчитать данные по исходным столбцам не понимаю. Направьте, пожалуйста, на верный путь

---

вот исходник excel: ID ФИО: 1234567890 9876543210 7894561230 6543219870 5678941230 8527419630 2058794612 3021456789 4178520369 9954786302 Атрибут A да нет нет да нет нет да нет да нет Атрибут B нет нет да да да нет нет нет да да

Comment: загрузите в pandas, пересчитайте, выгрузите новую таблицу

Comment: в pandas загрузил, возникают сложности с пересчетом и созданием заголовков для новой таблицы

Comment: пишите код - как загружали, как персчитывали, как выгружали, что получилось не так. Мы же не провидцы

Comment: правильно я понимаю, что сводная таблица для решения данной задачи не подойдет? уже начал в этй сторону копать

Comment: что такое сводная таблица?

Comment: использование pd.pivot_table

Comment: а вы не хотите нормально вопрос задать - привести пример тестовых данных, хотя бы. Гадать на кофейной гуще - занятие бессмысленное.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, наконец, автор начал давать хоть какую-то инфу

Что касается подсчетов, это можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'ФИО':
['1234567890', '9876543210', '7894561230', '6543219870', '5678941230', '8527419630', '2058794612', '3021456789', '4178520369', '9954786302', ],
'АтрибутA':
['да', 'нет', 'нет', 'да', 'нет', 'нет', 'да', 'нет', 'да', 'нет'],
'АтрибутB':
['нет', 'нет', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'нет', 'нет', 'нет', 'да', 'да']})

len(df)                                                          # 10
len(df[(df['АтрибутA'] == 'да') & (df['АтрибутB'] == 'да')])     # 2
len(df[df['АтрибутA'] == 'да'])                                  # 4     
len(df[df['АтрибутB'] == 'да'])                                  # 5
len(df[(df['АтрибутA'] != 'да') & (df['АтрибутB'] != 'да')])     # 3
```

Comment: df - это же просто старые данные.  вы создайте другой датафрейм, в него правильно сложите, а потом можно уже dfNew.to_excel вызывать. Или просто по ячейкам напишите заголовки и результат

Comment: Да, разобрался!
Очень вам благодарен!